# htaccess : Unable to maintain multiple projects and respective assets

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have just started `.htaccess` and facing problem in maintaining multiple websites. I have following directory structure

```
Apache Root
 |- Website1 
 |- Website2
 |- Website3
```

Now say for website1, I have

```
<script src="/js/logic.js"></script>
```

its not picking the `js` file. If I remove the starting `/` from the path, then also it becomes a problem as then it becomes relative path and final path ends in `index.php/js/logic.js`. How can I solve this problem.

Is there a way that I can specify a different root for each website, in its respective htaccess file or any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Typically each website would have it's own `VirtualHost` setup in Apache. The leading slash in each instance would make the path relative to the `DocumentRoot` value set for the given website. You can't share client-side assets with each of the sites set up this way because those need to be in a directory that is below or at the root.

Comment: @Marty : Then, how can I make a website pick up the proper assests in my localhost. What would be the correct htaccess file? Please help. Thanks

Comment: How are these websites setup in your `VirtualHost`?